# Sublabel inside SwiftUI Menu Button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, menu

I try to create a menu with buttons containing primary and secondary labels like the photo bellow using SwiftUI, so I embed the button and the text (as secondary label) in the VStack, but it's doesn't work.
How I can create this view in swiftUI?

[image]

The Code

```
 Menu {
        Section {
            search
        }
        Section {
// The sort button
        Menu  {
            Picker("Sorting options", selection: $sort) {
                ForEach(SortType.allCases, id: \.self) { type in
                    Label("title", systemImage: "chevron.up")
                        .tag(type)
                }
            }
        } label: {
// Here I should embed title and subtitle like the photo but I don't know how.
            Label("Sort By", systemImage: "arrow.up.arrow.down")
        }
        }
    } label: {
        menuLabel
    }
```

Comment: You should use this community to ask questions that can help you solve an issue, not for sharing your plans. If that was actually a question, please provide details of what you have tried and why you didn't succeed, after you tried [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=swift+implement+menu+button&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Comment: I'm sorry about the miss understanding, I edit the question to be clearer about what I want to ask.

Comment: Can you show your code so we can help you ? We can not supposed what you have done so far.

Comment: Present your attempt(s) and folks fill comment / make changes to help out. There’s got to be a bit of an initiative though from your side

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible in pure SwiftUI. Menu only accepts labels from one Text and one Image.

Comment: Indeed, like ChrisR said: that's not possible. There is a bit more that you can do, though. Check out this WWDC talk for more information: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10205

Comment: I checked out the WWDC talk, its don't allow me to do what I exactly need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using UIKit since iOS 15.0

```
var menu = UIMenu()

if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
   menu = UIMenu(title: "Sort By",
                 subtitle: "Name",
                 children: provideJobSortOptions())
} else {
   menu = UIMenu(title: "Sort By"), children: provideJobSortOptions())
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this is referring to a `UIMenu`, which is part of UIKit, not SwiftUI which the OP mentioned specifically.  Can you expand your example to show using a `UIMenu` in a SwiftUI `Menu`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

### NEW ANSWER

If you are attempting to get behavior similar to the below, use the `content` closure of a `Button`

[image]

```swift
Menu("HI") {
    Button(action: {}) {
        Text(temperatureType.localizedDescription)
        Text(formatTemperature(sensor.temperature, to: 
    temperatureType.toUnitTemperature()))
    }
}
```

Here, I am mimicking the new data detectors functionality provided in iOS 16's `UITextView` Then you can add any of the modifiers you would like

---

### OLD ANSWER

I found a partial way to do this, but it is without the subtitle text smaller and in a `foregroundStyle(.secondary)` :

[image]

```swift
Picker(selection: $pointsSortType) {
    Button(PointsSortType.date            .displayName) {}.tag(PointsSortType.date            .rawValue)
    Button(PointsSortType.type            .displayName) {}.tag(PointsSortType.type            .rawValue)
    Button(PointsSortType.submissionStatus.displayName) {}.tag(PointsSortType.submissionStatus.rawValue)
    Button(PointsSortType.duration        .displayName) {}.tag(PointsSortType.duration        .rawValue)
} label: {
    Label {
        Text("""
             Sort By
             Manual
             """)
    } icon: {
        Image(systemName: "arrow.up.arrow.down")
    }
}
.pickerStyle(.menu)
```

Here, we are using Multi-Line Strings to trick it. I tried messing around with adding multiple `Text`s in a bunch of `Stack`s. I even tried type erasing it with `AnyView(erasing:)`, but somehow it's still smarter. I even tried interpolating `Text` views and adding `Text` modifiers like Bold, but it overrode that as well.

Sorry for the spaces in between, but that is how I like to format my code.

Comment: I know this is not the best solution, but this can be used in the meanwhile. Another way of going about showing subtitle data is by using a Bullet Point
`Text("Sort By • Manual")`

![https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRGNz.png](Image)

Comment: Apparently a simple break line character also works "\n".

Comment: This is a nice find. Also, it's completely unexpected that the Menu would "accept" the second piece of Text and automatically style it to description style.
Adding the third Text won't work though.

Keep in mind the system limits the description to two lines of text, the tail will be trimmed.

Comment: does it work on macos too? would be amazing

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hacky solution you can use is to extend UIMenu and override its subtitle property. You can create a menu observer class that allows mutation of the value of that property.

something like this:

```
extension UIMenu {
  
  open override var subtitle: String? {
    get { MenuObserver.shared.menuSubtitle }
    set { }
  }
}

class MenuObserver {
  
  static var shared = MenuObserver()
  
  var menuSubtitle: String? = nil
}
```

Then you can update the menu subtitle anywhere in your code by changing the property of the observer

```
MenuObserver.shared.menuSubtitle = "someString"
```

This solution won't work though if you have multiple menu's embedded inside a menu as the same subtitle will show for each

PS. This solution works for SwiftUI as SwiftUI's menu is just a UIMenu under the hood